# Distinct Result via xQuery

Tags: distinct, xquery

I'm trying to get reviewers who review one or more books published after 2010.

```
for $r in doc("review.xml")//Reviews//Review,
    $b in doc("book.xml")//Books//Book
where $b/Title = $r/BookTitle
    and $b/Year > 2010
return {$r/Reviewer}
```

The following are both XML files.

review.xml:

```
<Reviews>
    <Review>
        <ReviewID>R1</ReviewID>
        <BookTitle>B1</BookTitle>
        <Reviewer>AAA</Reviewer>
    </Review>
    <Review>
        <ReviewID>R2</ReviewID>
        <BookTitle>B1</BookTitle>
        <Reviewer>BBB</Reviewer>
    </Review>
    <Review>
        <ReviewID>R3</ReviewID>
        <BookTitle>B2</BookTitle>
        <Reviewer>AAA</Reviewer>
    </Review>
    <Review>
        <ReviewID>R4</ReviewID>
        <BookTitle>B3</BookTitle>
        <Reviewer>AAA</Reviewer>
    </Review>
<Reviews>
```

book.xml:

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Title>B1</Title>
        <Year>2005</Year>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Title>B2</Title>
        <Year>2011</Year>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Title>B3</Title>
        <Year>2012</Year>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

I'll get two AAA by my xQuery code. I was wondering if I can get the distinct result, which means only one AAA. I've tried distinct-value() but don't know how to use it probably. Thanks for your reply!

----My Updated Solution with XML format for xQuery 1.0----

```
<root>
{
    for $x in distinct-values
    (
        for $r in doc("review.xml")//Reviews//Review,
            $b in doc("book.xml")//Books//Book
        where $b/Title = $r/BookTitle
            and $b/Year > 2010
        return {$r/Reviewer}
    )
    return <reviewer>{$x}</reviewer>
}
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve nodes, you can use the "group by" clause and select the first item of a group sequence:

```
for $r in doc("review.xml")//Review,
    $b in doc("book.xml")//Book
let $n := $r/Reviewer
where $b/Title = $r/BookTitle
  and $b/Year > 2010
group by $n
return $r[1]/Reviewer
```

Comment: I'm still using xQuery 1.0... I really appreciate your reply though!

Answer (score 1):

The following query will give you all distint reviewer names (note that the values are atomized, which means the element nodes are removed):

```
distinct-values(
  for $r in doc("review.xml")//Reviews//Review,
      $b in doc("book.xml")//Books//Book
  where $b/Title = $r/BookTitle
    and $b/Year > 2010
  return $r/Reviewer
)
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there any way that I can output the result with XML format?

Comment: @user1322538 You can do this approach first to get the names, then select the records using those names.